# How does PDOStatement::fetch() work internally?

Tags: php, database, pdo

I read everywhere that using `PDOStatement::fetch()` would mean you will not run out of memory, no matter how large the resultset is. So that begs the question: where are the rows stored?

PHP has to store the results somewhere when it gets them from the database. Where are these results stored? Or, are they stored in the database, and PHP has to query the database for the next row every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to reading a file, you open a stream and read data piece by piece, except that database internals are a way more complicated.

For example, look at the description of $driver_options [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), so you can even set scrollable cursor in order to control the direction of reading.

Answer (score 0):

[PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) will get you next row from your query. I don't think that it will not run out of memory (if one row contains lots of data) because your data will be held in memory (read about [Buffered and Unbuffered queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php#mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering)).